# How can I get place details from Google Places API for Android?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-places-api

I want to get details of places (cityName, ZipCode, etc) from predictions  that I get from Autocomplete Places service. My code is like the following:

```
    Places.GeoDataApi.getAutocompletePredictions(googleApiClient, query, bounds, null)
            .setResultCallback(
                    new ResultCallback<AutocompletePredictionBuffer>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResult(AutocompletePredictionBuffer buffer) {
                            if (buffer == null)
                                return;

                            if (buffer.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
                                for (AutocompletePrediction prediction : buffer) {
                                    // How to get cityName here
                                }
                            }
                            buffer.release();
                        }
                    }, 15, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

Is this possible? How can I implement it?
If I look for place details by placeId, I can't get that I want neither:

```
Places.GeoDataApi.getPlaceById(googleApiClient, placeId)
        .setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<PlaceBuffer>() {
            @Override
            public void onResult(PlaceBuffer places) {
                if (places.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
                    // How to get cityName here
                }
                places.release();
            }
        });
```

Comment: You can probably use a place ID to retrieve the coordinates, and use the coordinates to retrieve a city name. You can see [this StackOveflow answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2296416/4195406) for more details

Comment: I've already seen that post, but I'm interested in a more direct way. Thanks for your answer! :)

Comment: did you find any more direct way?

Comment: Not yet, I'm getting the place details in two steps..

Comment: Currently, you have to do at least two requests. Please upvote this feature request - https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35828699 to make it with a single request.

Answer (score 5):

You'll need to `Geocode` the place results to get back that information.

---

```
Places.GeoDataApi.getPlaceById(googleApiClient, placeId)
    .setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<PlaceBuffer>() {

        @Override
        public void onResult(PlaceBuffer places) {

            if (!places.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
                // Request did not complete successfully
                return;
            }

            // Setup Geocoder
            Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(getApplicationContext(), Locale.getDefault());
            List<Address> addresses;

            // Attempt to Geocode from place lat & long
            try {

                addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(
                    place.getLatLng().latitude, 
                    place.getLatLng().longitude, 
                    1);

                if (addresses.size() > 0) {

                    // Here are some results you can geocode
                    String ZIP;
                    String city;
                    String state;
                    String country;

                    if (addresses.get(0).getPostalCode() != null) {
                        ZIP = addresses.get(0).getPostalCode();
                        Log.d("ZIP", ZIP);
                    }

                    if (addresses.get(0).getLocality() != null) {
                        city = addresses.get(0).getLocality();
                        Log.d("city", city);
                    }

                    if (addresses.get(0).getAdminArea() != null) {
                        state = addresses.get(0).getAdminArea();
                        Log.d("state", state);
                    }

                    if (addresses.get(0).getCountryName() != null) {
                        country = addresses.get(0).getCountryName();
                        Log.d("country", country);
                    }

                }

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            places.release();
        }
    });
```

Comment: How to get the placeId?