# How to get city and state name in Autocomplete Places _ Places API

Tags: android, google-places-api, google-places, google-places-autocomplete

Iam using Places Autocomplete for selecting city from user, its working fine,
But now i want both city and state name..
my code..

**Initialising**

```
  List<Place.Field> fields = Arrays.asList(Place.Field.ID, Place.Field.NAME);
            Intent intent = new Autocomplete.IntentBuilder(
                    AutocompleteActivityMode.OVERLAY, fields)
                    .setTypeFilter(TypeFilter.CITIES)
                    .setCountry("IN")
                    .build(this);
            startActivityForResult(intent, AUTOCOMPLETE_REQUEST_CODE);
```

**onActivity Result**

```
if (requestCode == AUTOCOMPLETE_REQUEST_CODE) {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                //Place place = Autocomplete.getPlaceFromIntent(data);
                Place place = Autocomplete.getPlaceFromIntent(data);

                edit_profile_city_editText.setText(place.getName());

            } else if (resultCode == AutocompleteActivity.RESULT_ERROR) {
                Status status = Autocomplete.getStatusFromIntent(data);
                Log.i("Autocomplete error", status.getStatusMessage());
            } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
            }
        }
```

While selecting city from search bar its showing both city and state..
eg:**Chennai 
TamilNadu, India**
Kindly help how to get state name also...

Comment: Did you try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/37737253/6549598 ?

Comment: Iam using New PLACES API,  given link using old google places API which has been deprecated

Comment: update List<Place.Field> fields = Arrays.asList(Place.Field.ID, Place.Field.NAME,Place.Field.LAT_LNG); to get LatLong, otherwise it will be null.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use like this:-

**and onActivityResult**

```
 if (requestCode == AUTOCOMPLETE_REQUEST_CODE) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Place place = Autocomplete.getPlaceFromIntent(data);
            LatLng latLng = place.getLatLng();
            double MyLat = latLng.latitude;
            double MyLong = latLng.longitude;
            Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(EditProfileActivity.this, Locale.getDefault());
            try {
                List<Address> addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(MyLat, MyLong, 1);
                String stateName = addresses.get(0).getAdminArea();
                String cityName = addresses.get(0).getLocality();
                edit_profile_city_editText.setText(place.getName() + "," + stateName);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();

            }
```

Hope this will help you.Thanks..

Comment: iam getting error in this line "geocoder.getFromLocation(MyLat,MyLong,1);" error:java.io exception

Comment: Updated this issue by Try catch

Comment: update List<Place.Field> fields = Arrays.asList(Place.Field.ID, Place.Field.NAME,Place.Field.LAT_LNG); to get LatLong, otherwise it will be null.

Comment: worked perfectly fine. 
Just change place.getName() with cityName while setting text for the editProfile.

Answer (score 3):

**Try something like this:**

```
 Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(getContext(), Locale.getDefault());
 List<Address> addresses = new ArrayList<>();
 addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(lat, lng, 1);
 String country = addresses.get(0).getCountryName();
```

Answer (score 2):

I think these will work for you;

```
Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());
List<Address> addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(MyLat, MyLong, 1);
String cityName = addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(0);
String stateName = addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(1);
String countryName = addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(2);
```

or

```
String address = addresses.get(0).getSubLocality();
String cityName = addresses.get(0).getLocality();
String stateName = addresses.get(0).getAdminArea();
```